# Kendo mobile UI Listview nested Rendering on Android

Tags: android, ios, listview, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am working on a project using Kendo mobile and I have a listview with each item in the list linking to another view, on the first visit to the listview everything seems fine, but once I click to go to the linked page and use the back button to return to the listview I notice the listview has shrunk in width..inspection of the code reveals that the "km-listview-wrapper" DIV keeps nested itself thus the resulting shrinkage...on iOS this also occurs but the nesting does not affect the presentation.

Aside from the fact that this distorts the UI, it also increases the DOM elements and thus bloats things up unnecessarily. Below is a link to sample code
http://jsbin.com/oXAmaDu/3/edit
The above code is just to give an idea of the initial listview and how it is initialized and populated.

The kendo rendered code looks like this:

```
<div class="km-listview-wrapper">
    <ul id="currentEvents" data-role="listview" class="km-  widget km-listview km-list">
        <li data-uid="af8abf96-611e-443a-8e6c-8cf1e3dce176">    
           <a class="clear km-listview-link" data-eventid="123" data-role="listview-link" href="views/singleEventView.html?eventId=123">
               <div class="evContainer">
                 <div class="">Purple Rain</div>
                 <div class="">MSG</div>          
               </div>
           </a>    
        </li>
        <li data-uid="0e69a5c8-f494-4fa4-ae58-bcf413defc91">    
           <a class="clear km-listview-link" data-eventid="124" data-role="listview-link" href="views/singleEventView.html?eventId=124">
               <div class="evContainer">
                   <div class="">Blue Man Group</div>
                   <div class="">Vegas</div>          
               </div>
            </a>    
        </li>
        <li data-uid="cbf2df5a-7689-411e-8e4f-a8e27e718530">
            <a class="clear km-listview-link" data-eventid="125" data-role="listview-link" href="views/singleEventView.html?eventId=125">
                <div class="evContainer">
                    <div class="">Red November</div>
                    <div class="">AC</div>          
                </div>
             </a>    
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After clicking on a list item and navigating away then returning back, the render code nest like this:

```
<div class="km-listview-wrapper">
    <div class="km-listview-wrapper">...</div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever get any further with this?  I have noticed the same thing and think its the culprit for some scrolling issues I am having.

Comment: @zkent Yes, it was due to the fact the listview was getting reinitialized on "show", I needed to create my listview on "show" as opposed to on "init" which would have fixed the issue since that would've been initialized once. My fix was to check if the listview was undefined before creating it and refreshing it otherwise. Hope that helps.